# Appending data to empty pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append

To start, I am very new to Python and stackoverflow. I am sorry if this question has come up before, but I could not find it in the forum. Could someone please explain why this output happens when I try to append data to a Dataframe.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   0   1   2   3   4   5   6

0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
```

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"])

testdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

dftest = dftest.append([testdata])
```

I want the testdata to appear under the columns like this.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G

1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Comment: `append` is getting deprecated. Why are you trying to add data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
import pandas as pd
dftest = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"])
testdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]


dftest.loc[len(dftest)] = testdata
dftest
```